# pandas groupby - case sensitive issues in groups

Tags: python, string, pandas

I need to groupby a DataFrame by a column named "Keyword", with:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Keyword')
```

Then I'm searching for the size of each group:

```
a = grouped.size()
```

And the results are like these:

```
Keyword
ATTORNEY            48
Appraiser           94
Attorney          1437
BASEBOARD            2
BELL PEPPER          1
BULLETIN BOARD       1
Bell Pepper         36
Bell pepper         19
Bulletin Board      20
Bulletin board       3
CANDY              765
CANDy                2
CANdy                1
...                ...
```

I would like to avoid case sensitive issues, and get a unique group for words like "CANDY, CANDy, CANdy" etc, which differ only for some lower or upper characters. I tried to escape this problem setting to `df['Keyword'].str.lower()` before grouping, but it doesn't work.
Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you remember to assign the result of `.lower()` back? so did you do :`df['Keyword'] = df['Keyword'].str.lower()`?

Comment: Sorry, that was the issue! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just as a followup to this you don't actually need to overwrite the keyword when you do the grouping. You can instead do the whole transformation in the  call to `groupby`

```
grouped = df.groupby(df['Keyword'].str.lower())
```

So as an example you could then have:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Keyword': ['Attorney', 'ATTORNEY', 'foo'], 'x' : [1, 2, 42]})

df.groupby(df['Keyword'].str.lower()).sum()
```

Which outputs:

```
           x
Keyword     
attorney   3
foo       42
```

as you would expect